# tabbar rotating

Tags: iphone

is it possible to rotate Tabbar with all  items(tabbar controller) as it is in landscape when particular touch event is happening in one view (portrait) without shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, but you need to call

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
```

Which is an undocumented api, and it will cause the appstore to regect your app.

FYI, I've created a nifty solution to rotating tabbar controllers, you can read about it here:
[BAGTabbarController](http://table14software.com/code_posts/11)

Comment: there is no way to turn tabbar for landscape without using private API?

Comment: BAGTabBarController is used in iRef-Kickball, www.itunes.com/apps/iref-kickball